# Use a Variable on smtplib

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtplib

Is it possible to use variables in the content of **smtplib** `set_content()` as shown in the image or code below.

Thanks!

```
msg = EmailMessage()
            
            server = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver.com')
            server.set_debuglevel(2)

            msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
            msg['From'] = 'no-reply@mailserver.com'
            msg['To'] = email
            emailCustomerName = str(customerName)

            msg.set_content('''
--- Begin JSON ---
{
"Value1":<variableValue>,
"Value2":"String Value",
"Value3":2.6,
'''
)
```

[Variables on smtplib Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZpFO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the same:
The way to solve this is to concatenate the strings and the variables using three single quotation marks `(''')`.

For example:

```
msg.set_content(
'''String1''' + variable1 + ''' String2''' + variable2 + '''String3''' + ...
)
```

Hope this is useful!

Answer (score 0):

587 is added in case of wifi problem (TimeoutError: [WinError 10060])

```py
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as connection:
    connection.starttls()  # this line of code make the connection secure
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
    connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=my_email,
            to_addrs="email@outlook.com",
            msg="Subject:Iam subject\n\n"
                + daily_quote)
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could use :

```
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as connection:
    connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
    connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=my_email,
            to_addrs="email@outlook.com",
            msg=f"Subject:I am subject'\n\n{body_var}")
```